# Getting Internal Server Error 500 on Graphql Mutation

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo

[image: As you can see that this query is showing the correct error message]

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            val req = RequestCodeMutation(phoneNumber)
            val response = try {
                ApolloClientManager
                    .apolloClient
                    .suspendMutate(req)
            }
            catch (e: ApolloException) {
                println(e.message)
                isError.value = true
                null
            }
            finally {
                loading.value = false
            }
            val requestCode = response?.data?.requestCode
            println(response?.errors)
}
```

```
suspend fun <D : Operation.Data, T, V : Operation.Variables> ApolloClient.suspendMutate(mutation: Mutation<D, T, V>): Response<T> =
    mutate(mutation).toDeferred().await()
```

This is my validator on server side. It is shown correctly on Graphiql, however, I am unable to receive this message on client side.

```
requestCode = async (resolve, source, args, context, info) => {
        let { phoneNumber } = args;

        phoneNumber = validator.trim(phoneNumber);
        Object.assign(args, { phoneNumber });

        if (!validator.isMobilePhone(phoneNumber)) {
            throw new UserInputError('Invalid phone number provided!');
        }

        return resolve(source, args, context, info);
    }
```

`ApolloException.message` is showing Internal Server Error and `response?.errors` is `null`.
`response?.errors` is not supposed to be `null` and show the proper error message that is being shown on GraphiQL.

Comment: You are returning `null` in your catch block. So response is null, so is `response?.errors`

Comment: @ChristianB if i return anything else, it does not allow me to access the data property of response. What should be returned in that block?

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block, you can build a new [Response](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/blob/main/apollo-api/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/apollographql/apollo/api/Response.kt), based on the `ApolloCall`.

So consider the following:

```kotlin
import com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response
import com.apollographql.apollo.api.Error

fun <T> executeCall(call: ApolloCall<T>): Response<T> = try {
  apolloCall.toDeferred().await()
} catch (apolloException: ApolloException) {
  val error = Error(apolloException.message ?: "Unknown Error")
  Response.builder(apolloCall.operation()).errors(listOf(error)).build()
}
```

*Note: I assume that `ApolloClientManager.apolloClient.suspendMutate(req)` returns an instance of `ApolloCall<T>`.*

You can then use this function like:

```kotlin
val call =  ApolloClientManager.apolloClient.suspendMutate(RequestCodeMutation(phoneNumber))
val response = executeCall(call)

// check the response status code
```

Comment: I updated my answer a little. Hope it will help you.

Comment: `apolloException.message` is still going to be internal server error. I want the message to be `Invalid phone number provided

Comment: I do not know what you mean or what your exact problem is. As I showed, you could just create a new error - message if you catch the exception. You could just create a new error: `val error = Error("Invalid phone number provided")`. Hope that helps you.

Comment: I have edited my question, you might be able to understand it better now

Comment: What is the response code? Is it a 2xx or some error? If you get an `ApolloException` what is the message it contains?

Comment: `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` This is exactly what it contains

Comment: Please debug your `Response` you receive. I guess `data` is null. `errors` can be a list. Does none of the properties of `Response` contain the error message from the server?

Comment: response itself is null

Comment: How can the response be null, when you get `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`? Are you still returning `null` from your catch block? I do not know if this makes sense to continue, because we are going in circles.

Comment: okay wait, response is not null now. the data property is null, and there is a list of errors. However, the errors list contains only one error and that error is same that we created in catch block and the message is `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`. I have debugged the response as much as I could, and could not find any message from the server.

Comment: I suggest two things, remove the try catch, just get the response, and look at those errors. You just introduced try-catch to print something and to set a boolean, you basically do not need those. The "real" response should contain everything. If the desired message, is not included at all, its an issue of Apollo's implementation. You should ask on [GitHub](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues) how to get your specific error message.

Comment: If i do not add try catch, the application crashes